# TM1 VUSLICE, how to make it work VBA

Tags: vba, excel, cognos-tm1

```
Sub Exportview()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Run("VUSLICE", "server:cube", "MyView")
End Sub
```

I've been trying to make the VUSLICE tm1 function to work for me.
I'm only getting "FALSE" as an output in cell (1,1).

Can someone please help me out on how I should be coding this particular piece?
I'm expecting the view to be exported into excel?

I tried E_PICK function in the same format as above, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, there's no problem with it.
Just ensure that you are connected to TM1 Server, and the View you are trying to import is public and not private.
Hope this helps.

```
Run "VUSLICE", "ServerName" & ":" & "CubeName", "ViewName"
```